# Create drupal node programatically from excel vba

Tags: php, vba, drupal-6

I am a decent VBA programmer but I have no experience with PHP and very little with Drupal. We created a drupal site and a few custom CCK content types but there is one thing i would like to implement and i have no idea how. 
Is there a way I could create a node for my specific content type, by passing the values from an excel file ?

To be more explicit, I have an excel file with 6 columns and a content type with 6 fields matching the columns in excel. Now I want to have a vba procedure that will take the values in my 6 columns and pass them to another script (I assume) which will create the node using the values from my vba procedure.
So something like :

```
Call Create_node (a1.value,b1.value,c1.value,d1.value,e1.value,f1.value)
```

Is something like this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module. You can export your Excel data as CSV and have Feeds easily convert it into nodes as you described.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the reply. I did check the Feeds module but I don't think it does what I need, or at least I don't know how to make it. to create a node using the feeds module I should still navigate to the www.domain.com/import page and load the file from there, I'm trying to find a fully automated solution, not sure if it's possible by using the feeds module.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this module "Node import" may help you

http://drupal.org/project/node_import